# Why does the linker not fail when an extern const is changed in another file?

Tags: c++, linker, constants, extern

I have the following two files

```
//###########
//a.cpp
//###########
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    extern int var; //Why is this allowed?
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
    var = 99; //Core dump happens here
    std::cout << var << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
//###########
//b.cpp
//###########
extern const int var = 41;
```

Here, compilation and linking happens without any problem. When I run, I get core dump while trying to set the value of "var" to 99. I want to know why I am allowed to declare a non-const var in a.cpp. Shouldn't the linker fail to link this?

Comment: I do not know if the standard addresses this issue.  What tool chain are you using?

Comment: @brianbeuning: The standard does address this in C++11 3.5/1: "the types specified by all declarations referring to a given variable or function shall be identical". It also says "A violation of this rule on type identity does not require a diagnostic", so the linker is not obliged to check the type.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I thought const was a storage class and not considered part of the type.

Comment: @brianbeuning: CV-qualifiers are part of an object's type; see C++11 3.9.3 for the gory details.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, your program is "incorrect" according to the C++ standard. I'm not sure if it ends up beting "Undefined behaviour" or some other classification of "You shouldn't really be doing this, it's wrong".

However, it's hard for the compiler to convey sufficient information for the linker to spot this type of error, as the linker doesn't really understand "what you are doing" (e.g. writing to a `const` is not valid, but the linker doesn't understand that the operations are a write - it just knows that "you want the address of `var` here).

Since you are essentially lying to the compiler, you are doing this to yourself. C and C++ are full of cases where you have to keep yourself honest with the compiler, or things may go horribly wrong, but the compiler doesn't always help you spot these things (often because it's hard to achieve in a reliable way).

Comment: In my case I agree, I am not being honest with the compiler. But this is an honest error which any beginner can make ;)

Comment: Sure, and there are lots of other possible "honest errors" that could lead to similar problems. Unfortunately, C and C++ are languages that have limited guards against some types of abuse. This is why you should be very careful with these things - in this case, for example, using a header-file to "publish" the `extern` variable across the two units of code would solve that problem - because if you have a `extern int var;` and `const int var;` in the same compile unit, you get at least a warning (`g++` makes it an error about conflicting declaration).